# ie8 Object doesn't support this for extjs code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, extjs, backbone.js, extjs4

- i am getting the following error: "`Object doesn't support this
  property or method`" in ie8
- in chrome its fine
- when i debug ext js code in ie8 its shows undefined for
  `region.getWorld();`
- but where as when I see it in chrome browser I am getting the values
- providing my code below, can you guys tell me what is the problem

```js
allWidth: function() {
    var me = this,
        states = me.getstates(),
        waterY = 0,
        placeY = 0,
        World;

    states.forEach(function(region) {
        World = region.getWorld();
        if (World.y < placeY) {
            placeY = World.y;
        }
        if (World.y + World.height > waterY) {
            waterY = World.y + World.height;
        }
    });

    return waterY - placeY;
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 doesn't support the `forEach` method for Arrays. You have a few options to fix this.

You could use a normal for loop:

```js
for(var i = 0; i < states.length; i++){
    var region = states[i];
    /* ... */
```

Since you're using extjs, you could also use the `Ext.each` method instead:

```js
Ext.each(states, function(region){
...
```

Or you could use a shim/polyfill to add the `forEach` method in IE8.

You can find a polyfill for the `forEach` method on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill).

Comment: any idea how to convert this one here.layout.getStates().forEach(function(State) {
            StateBox.push({
               
            });
        });

Comment: this is how you could do it using the function in ExtJS. `Ext.each(layout.getStates(), function(state){ StateBox.push({}); });`

Comment: @weeksdev did u miss here by mistake in ur answer here.layout.getStates().

Comment: yeah, lol, thought that was the end of your previous sentence.